# Django output html time is 8 hours ahead of database time

Tags: django, python-2.7

I'm very new to **Django** and I've been learning the framework from the book *"Practical django Projects"* (the book teaches us to write a cms).  My code runs fine, but I have time problem with the `get_absolute_url` function below.  It's actually outputting the link 8 hours ahead of the time saved in my database. I used python shell to look at the saved time in the database and the time saved in the admin interface, they are all correct.  But when I use the `get_absolute_url func` below to generate the link in browser, it becomes 8 hours ahead and throws the day off.  I set the correct zone in my Django setting file.  I cannot figure out what's wrong.

How I can fix this (I'm using sqlite3 for my database, Django 1.4.1)?

Here is my code for the Entry class:

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from tagging.fields import TagField
from markdown import markdown
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str

class Entry(models.Model):

live = LiveEntryManager()
objects = models.Manager()
#define constant options
LIVE_STATUS = 1
DRAFT_STATUS = 2
HIDDEN_STATUS = 3
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (LIVE_STATUS, 'Live'),
    (DRAFT_STATUS,'Draft'),
    (HIDDEN_STATUS, 'Hidden'),
    )
#adding features to admin interface
class Meta:
    ordering = ['-pub_date']
    verbose_name_plural = "Entries"    
#define model fields:
title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
excerpt = models.TextField(blank=True) #It's ok to not add anything for this field
body = models.TextField()
pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now()) 
slug = models.SlugField(unique_for_date='pub_date')

enable_comments = models.BooleanField(default=True)
featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=LIVE_STATUS)
#HTML
excerpt_html = models.TextField(editable=False, blank=True)
body_html = models.TextField(editable=False, blank=True)
#third party:
tag = TagField()
#relationship fields:
categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
author = models.ForeignKey(User)
#define methods:
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):#modify the model.save() method
    self.body_html = markdown(self.body)
    if self.excerpt:
        self.excerpt_html = markdown(self.excerpt)#from excerpt field to excerpt_html
    super(Entry, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "%s" % self.pub_date.strftime("year:%Y/day:%d/hour:%H/minute:%M/second:%S")
#@models.permalink
#def get_absolute_url(self):
    #return ('coltrane_entry_detail', (), {'year': self.pub_date.strftime("%Y"),
                                          'month': self.pub_date.strftime("%b").lower(),
                                          'day': self.pub_date.strftime("%d"),
                                          'slug': self.slug})
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

This is my entry_archive.html:

```
{% extends "base_entries.html"%}

{%block title%}{{block.super}} | Latest entries{% endblock %}


{% block content %}
{% for entry in latest %} 

<h2>{{entry.title}}</h2>
<p>Published on {{ entry.pub_date|date:"F j P s, Y" }}</p>
{% if entry.excerpt_html%}
    {{entry.excerpt_html|safe}}
{% else %}
    {{entry.body_html|truncatewords_html:"50"|safe}}
{% endif%}
<p><a href="{{entry.get_absolute_url}}">Read full entry ...</a></p>

{% endfor %}
{%endblock%}

{%block whatis%}
 <p>This is a list of the latest {{latest.count}} entries published in my blog.</p>

{% endblock %}
```

I couldn't post screenshot because i'm a new user.  {{ entry.pub_date|date:"F j P s, Y" }} in my html give me correct time:  December 28 11:24 a.m. 45, 2012.  But {{entry.get_absolute_url}} gives me year:2012/day:28/hour:19/minute:24/seconds:45

I add the () to pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now()) as you guys suggested, but the result is still the same(the book actually suggests not to add () ).  The thing troubles me is that {{ entry.pub_date|date:"F j P s, Y" }} gives me the correct time on my html, but {{entry.get_absolute_url}} is 8 hours ahead.  I set my setting.py time zone to TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'.  Thanks for all the quick response, but this is killing me...

Comment: looks like a timezone problem. Which timezones are you and your servers located in?

Comment: check TIME_ZONE value in settings.py

Comment: `pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)` should be `pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())` see the missing `()` after `.now`

Answer (score 0):

change the following:

```
pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

to Either

```
pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

or

```
pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```